# What is the difference between qDebug() used as a stream and as a function

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I have seen bits of Qt code that uses qDebug as if it were `printf()`

```
qDebug( format, ... );
```

Mostly i see it used like `std::cout`

```
qDebug() << "one " << var_one;
```

What is the difference in the usages and when is it correct/better to use one of the other?  The Qt help online somehow seems to reference the function version but never explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`qDebug(pattern, object1, object2)` it's basically the old fashioned `fprintf(stderr, pattern, object1, object2)`, as such you depend on compiler support to avoid - for instance - to crash your program with wrong patterns, like `int x; qDebug("%s\n", x);`. Well, GCC catches this one, but the compiler *cannot always* know if the pattern is appropriate, I think.

I always use `qDebug() << object << ...;`, as the documentation states

> If you include QtDebug, a more convenient syntax is also available:

```
qDebug() << "Brush:" << myQBrush << "Other value:" << i;
```

> With this syntax, the function returns a QDebug object that is configured to use the QtDebugMsg message type. It automatically puts a single space between each item, and outputs a newline at the end. It supports many C++ and Qt types.

you can pass most of Qt objects to qDebug() << ... and get them rendered in readable way

try for instance `qDebug() << QTime::currentTime();`

Comment: I'm using qDebug in next way (if I need complex formatting): `qDebug() << QString( "%1 - %2" ).arg( "something1").arg( 42 );`

Comment: it's more complex than needed: better `qDebug() << "something" << " - " << 42`;`

Comment: it's not complex. If you need to out a lot of string, combined with arguments - you will write a lot of code. Compare, what is more readable: `qDebug() << QString("Coordinates: \"%1 x %2 x %3\"").arg(x[i]).arg(y[i]).arg(z[i]);` or `qDebug() << "Coordinates: \"" << x[i] << " x " << y[i] << " x " << z[i]; << "\""`

Comment: IMHO, the whole << version of stream output is clumsy.  `printf()` is far more easly formatted.  Imagine the mix of `width()` and `fill()` tokens that would go in the previous example if it were being formatted into a table or form.

Comment: I found this information about [qDebug()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qDebug) as a function.